# export to csv using jupyter notebook separator error

Tags: python, excel, pandas, import

I have a problem exporting to CSV
The number I calculated in python doesn't right after I import to csv and open In excel

```
count_sector = nsaham.groupby("Sector[["Sector","LastPrice"]].agg({"Sector":"count","LastPrice":"mean"})
count_sector1 = count_sector.rename(columns{"Sector":"count_sector","LastPrice":"average_price"})
count_sector1.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(count_sector1.sort_values("count_sector",ascending=False))
```

[output count_sector1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBd45.png)

but after I open in excel the average_price columns change? any insight to solve this

```
count_sector1.to_csv("jumlahsaham.csv",float_format='%.3f',sep=";")
```

[excel: after import from csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKhBI.png)

Comment: I'm wondering if this is confusion arising from dots vs commas as 1000s separator https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_with_numbers.htm

Comment: i think so it's a dot vs comma problem, is any command to solve this? i already set the dot to comma and vice versa in excel but the output still same

Comment: What does your csv look like in a text editor? Post a line of it?